# How to pass timestamp value in Oracle Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table column which has timestamp data type. How to pass timestamp value to the table column? I am passing to_timestamp('1240','HH:MI:SS') in oracle procedure. In DB table I have a value like  01-AUG-20 12.40.00.000000000 PM . I only want to store timestamp in the DB table. Is there a way? Please guide me on this. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean only you want to store the time ? Because timestamp data type includes date with time information?

Comment: yes I want to store only time also I want to ask why while inserting, wrong date value is getting inserted?

Comment: It is the correct date; you are just making the assumption that `TO_DATE( '12:40', 'HH24:MI' )` should set the date to today's date when it doesn't and sets the day to the first of the current month.

Comment: [From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-4D95F6B2-8F28-458A-820D-6C05F848CA23): "If you specify a date value without a date, then the default date is the first day of the current month." That applies to timestamps too.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be confused about what the values store. A `TIMESTAMP` data type stores a date and time with year, month, day, hour, minute, second and optional fractional seconds and time zone components; you cannot have a `TIMESTAMP` with just hour, minute and second components as it will always have year-day components.

If you want to store time then either:

- Use an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type (with zero days);
- Use a `DATE` (or, if you want fractional seconds, `TIMESTAMP`) data type and set the year-day components to a fixed value (or ignore them);
- Use a string in a fixed format; or
- Store the number of seconds after midnight and use `TO_DATE( value, 'SSSSS' )` to convert to a date and then `TO_CHAR` to format it as needed.

I would say that if you want to add times then use an `INTERVAL` data type as it will natively support that.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE times1 ( value INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND );

INSERT INTO times1 ( value ) VALUES ( INTERVAL '12:40' HOUR TO MINUTE );

SELECT * FROM times1;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | VALUE               |
> | :------------------ |
> | +00 12:40:00.000000 |
> ```

If you want to display times then use a `DATE` and ignore the year-to-day components as you can easily format the time using `TO_CHAR`.

For example:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

CREATE TABLE times2 ( value DATE );

INSERT INTO times2 ( value )
-- Fixed date
SELECT DATE '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL '12:40' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
-- Today's date
SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '12:40' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
-- First of current month
SELECT TO_DATE( '12:40', 'HH24:MI' ) FROM DUAL;

SELECT value, TO_CHAR( value, 'HH24:MI' ) FROM times2;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> VALUE               | TO_CHAR(VALUE,'HH24:MI')
> :------------------ | :-----------------------
> 1970-01-01 12:40:00 | 12:40                   
> 2020-08-05 12:40:00 | 12:40                   
> 2020-08-01 12:40:00 | 12:40
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=176081831285e29514bd8479f2aa7475)*

Comment: Just curious, what's your view on storing seconds past midnight and converting as needed with SSSSS (and then ignoring the date part)?

Comment: @AlexPoole That works too and I've added it to the list. However, to convert to a human readable string requires converting the integer value to a date and then converting the date to a string so it depends on what operation you are going to perform most often as to what is going to be most efficient.